# Cannot delete tracks from a Spotify playlist using the Spotify API. Receiving 401 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, spotify

I've been trying and failing to delete tracks from a playlist using the API. Every method I attempt results in a 401 error from spotify.

This is a JavaScript Web App and I'm performing both Oauth and delete requests from a Node.js backend.

I have a valid Oauth2 flow and can create/add tracks to playlists on an authorized account.

I am using the passport.js Spotify Strategy to secure an access token and I have defined scopes of  'user-read-email',  'user-read-private', 'playlist-modify-public',  'playlist-modify-private',

Here is the code for my route handler in Node/express:

```
app.get('/api/playlist/update', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
// * ----- CONFIG ----- (Spotify access token)
const config = {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${req.user.accessToken}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
};

// * ----- GET SNAPSHOT ID OF PLAYLIST -----
const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${keys.URI_TOP10}`;

const response = await axios.get(url, config);
const snapshot_id = response.data.snapshot_id;

// console.log(snapshot_id);

// * get tracks
const responseTracks = await axios.get(
  `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${keys.URI_TOP10}/tracks`,
  config
);
const tracks = responseTracks.data.items;
const trackURIs = tracks.map((track) => {
  return { uri: track.track.uri };
});

// console.log(trackURIs);

// * ----- FORMATE FETCH REQ BODY -----
const body = JSON.stringify({
  snapshot_id: snapshot_id,
  tracks: trackURIs,
});

// console.log(body);

// * ----- DELETE PLAYLIST TRACKS -----
fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${keys.URI_TOP10}/tracks`, {
  method: 'DELETE',
  headers: config,
  body: body,
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log(
        `Tracks successfully deleted from playlist with ID ${keys.URI_TOP10}`
      );
    } else {
      console.log(response);
      throw new Error('Error deleting tracks from playlist');
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Maybe `headers: config.headers` instead of `headers: config`? Why are you not using axios like other requests?

Comment: You are a hero. Thank you for this. I was banging my head against the wall all over the place. I started this task with axios and the long line of troubleshooting led me to this coding pattern (specifically adding the snapshot ID to the fetch). I'll be refactoring to axios now that I'm on the rails.